# Get notified when NSTextField resigns first-responder status without subclassing

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, first-responder

I have an `NSTextField` which I add to the view hierarchy of my custom view and set the position for when the user clicks inside that custom view.

If the text field resigns first-responder status, e.g. because the user has clicked inside another `NSTextField` in the window, I need to fetch its value and remove it from the view hierarchy again.

How can my custom view get notified of the `NSTextField` it owns resigning first-responder status without having to subclass this text field just for this single purpose?

The `NSTextFieldDelegate` method `control:textShouldEndEditing:` won't do because it only gets called when the user actually edited something in the text field. I also need to hide the text field if the user didn't make any edits in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSTextField losing focus can be caught by :

```
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

Comment: aNotification contains all the information...NSLog it and check :)

Comment: Now I see, thanks! I probably should have read Apple's documentation on `NSControlTextDidEndEditingNotification` more carefully. I had missed the part where it says "The notification object is the `NSControl` object posting the notification.".

Comment: Thanks Anoop - I just needed to hook up a delegate to the textfield. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

One more delegate method is there which will do the same thing:-

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)command
{
    if (command==@selector(insertTab:) || (command==@selector(insertBacktab:)))
    {
      //Your Code
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Note:- It will work only for tab and backTab key